# Split large CSV file into multiple smaller CSV files using javascript, react

Tags: csv, split, chunks

I have a large csv file, even several million records. Is it possible on the client side, using javascript, to split this large file into several smaller ones (for example 100k records)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

1. user choose a file
2. you add an event on file loaded and store results in a variable
3. use `filedata.split("\n")` to split file into lines (create big array of items)
4. save each 100k part of the array into a variable and use `array.join("\n")` create the new files content.
5. create a download link for each file

In Step 5 you will have same data you started with in stap 1, if you want to put again the header of csv (name of columns) you can add them at the top of the array in the step 4, for the download link add csv at the end of the file name. here an example of how the code should look like.

```
// function called on file change event
function updatefile(event) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function () {
        // you do your split function here 
        var allItems = reader.result.split("\n");
        // 1) you split allitems into smaller arrays of 100k
        // 2) you save each item in to array and convert it to text again
        // it is possible that you need to add your csv header to the top
        // of the array  (for item 0 it is already there) for others 
        // (itms100Array[1].unshift(allItems[0])
        var item100kFileData[0] = item100kArray[0].join("\n");
        // 3) Create an object URL for a blob that contain the item
        // 4) add the download link to HTML       
     };
     reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
     // other code here
} // end of function file update
```

Comment: But then each chunk won't be type of csv file?

Comment: @jan.kowalski, spliting into an array does not change the format of the file, split then join will get you back from where you started, but now you have a smaller file size

Comment: TS lint talking to me that Property 'split' does not exist on type 'File'.

Comment: you do not appay split to your file, you do that to your onload results

Comment: I added an example of how the code should looks like to my answer